# What is the differences between these three words?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary, word-order

1. tell apart
2. say apart
3. speak apart

please tell me about differences between these words.
And also what do they mean?
Are they expressions?

Comment: Have you tried to Google the expressions?

Comment: Yes I tried. And I didn't find in dic

Comment: [tell apart](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/apart#apart__13)

Comment: *tell apart* 1. distinguish or separate one from another. "the twins were so identical that it was impossible to tell them apart." The other two are not idiomatic phrases.

Comment: OK. I saw it. What do other two mean?

Comment: Is it synonym? or not?

Comment: difference **between**, and i suppose, three

Comment: Sorry what? I didn't understand

Comment: This question would be better asked at [ell.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to tell apart or to tell the difference between things means to distinguish and is an expression.

"say apart" and "speak apart" do not work.

"to tell", "to say" and "to speak", without the additional "apart" are indeed similar, though not necessarily interchangeable. Apart from the difference in how they take objects and which prepositions are used when needed (tell someone something / say something to someone / speak to someone about something) there are small differences in meaning which are better understood by finding and reading examples (see [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online) for resources from where you can find examples - i.e. dictionaries)